# Issue with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) while using junit4 on Spring 4.3.0 and MAVEN 3.3.9

Tags: spring, java-8, maven-3, junit4

I am a newbie with Spring MVC and have been trying with a simple Integration test while using Spring Test context framework. The main issue is that a number of imports namely org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration,  org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration cannot be resolved. I have been playing around with pom dependencies - however, the problem still persists.

The following is the associated pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
  <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My validator test class (ProductValidatorTest.java) looks as follows:

```
package com.packt.webstore.validator;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import com.packt.webstore.config.WebApplicationContextConfig;
import com.packt.webstore.domain.Product;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebApplicationContextConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()
public class ProductValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductValidator productValidator;
    @Test
    public void
    product_without_UnitPrice_should_be_invalid() {
        //Arrange
        Product product = new Product();
        BindException bindException = new BindException(product, " product");
        //Act
        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(productValidator, product, bindException);
        //Assert
        Assert.assertEquals(1, bindException.getErrorCount());
        Assert.assertTrue(bindException.getLocalizedMessage().contains("Unit price is Invalid. It cannot be empty."));
    }
    @Test
    public void product_with_existing_productId_invalid() {

        //Arrange
        Product product = new Product("P1234","iPhone 5s", new BigDecimal(500));
        product.setCategory("Tablet");
        BindException bindException = new BindException(product, " product");
        //Act
        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(productValidator, product, bindException);
        //Assert
        Assert.assertEquals(1, bindException.getErrorCount());
        Assert.assertTrue(bindException.getLocalizedMessage().contains("A product already exists with this product id."));
    }
    @Test
    public void a_valid_product_should_not_get_any_error_during_validation() {
        //Arrange
        Product product = new Product("P9876","iPhone 5s", new BigDecimal(500));
        product.setCategory("Tablet");
        BindException bindException = new BindException(product, " product");
        //Act
        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(productValidator, product, bindException);
        //Assert
        Assert.assertEquals(0, bindException.getErrorCount());
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to get this fixed?

Comment: If you're writing integration tests, using SpringRunner and not SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Comment: I tried with that too - but still the rest isn't working

Comment: I would start by simplifying things.  From reading through the test cases you have here, I see no reason why you need 

@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebApplicationContextConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()

Remove these for starters.  Also, provide what errors you're actually getting and that will help the community answer your questions.

Comment: @lane.maxell: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type SpringRunner not present